# My query is updating all of the records instead of just 1, codeigniter4

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Hi all here is a snippet of the function for my update record

```
public function updateRecord()
{
    helper(['form', 'url']);
    $model = new EmployeeModel();

    $id = $this->request->getVar('emp_id');
    echo $id;

    $data = [
        'emp_fname' => $this->request->getVar('emp_fname'),
        'emp_lname' => $this->request->getVar('emp_lname'),
        'emp_mname' => $this->request->getVar('emp_mname'),
        'emp_status' => $this->request->getVar('emp_status'),
        'emp_position' => $this->request->getVar('emp_position'),
    ];

    $save = $model->update($id, $data);
    
    return redirect()->to(base_url('display'));
}
```

Comment: Well how the update statement is applied will depend on the code in the `$model->update()` method, so can you add that to your question please

Comment: You might want to try print your query using `getCompiledUpdate()` instead of `update()` in order to debug it and see what exactly is running.

Answer (score 1):

In your model change the primaryKey config option to your custom primary key name:

protected $primaryKey = 'emp_id';

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html#models

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it seems that using a custom ID on the database does not work with the query statements in CI4.

I changed my emp_id to id in the database itself and it solved the issue.

Comment: You should have changed it in your model and not your database.